# Snowflake SQL stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is the stored procedure I am using, I am using SQL as the language, and I am unable to parameterize the DL_FILE_NAME in the code exactly. The stored procedure is getting created, but when I call the stored procedure file, is not getting replaced in the DL_FILE_NAME, do you have any idea how to parameterize it when the language used as SQL. Please help with the correct stored procedure.

Here is the code of that stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TRANSFORM.SP_WMS_CDC_TDHIST_STAGE_LOAD_COPY(DL_FILE_NAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE STAGING.TDHIST_STG;

    COPY INTO STAGING.TDHIST_STG FROM (
      SELECT
        $1:TDPNT,
        $1:TDCUS,
        $1:TDTIC,
        $1:TDTSK,
        $1:TDOLC,
        $1:TDSEQ,
        $1:TDSL1,
        $1:TDCAS,
        $1:TDQTY,
        $1:TDCUB,
        $1:TDPRD,
        $1:TDBCD,
        $1:TDLIN,
        $1:TDMOP,
        $1:TDMMOP,
        $1:TDTYP,
        $1:TDSDT,
        $1:TDPOI,
        $1:TDSTP,
        $1:TDDCK,
        $1:TDSTS,
        $1:TDRCD,
        $1:TDDCD,
        $1:TDUSR,
        $1:TDCHK,
        $1:TDCSTS,
        $1:TDLDR,
        $1:TDDOR,
        $1:TDLOT,
        $1:TDLTX,
        $1:TDLIC,
        $1:TDPID,
        $1:TDLCE,
        $1:TDLDT,
        $1:TDLTM,
        $1:TDNCE,
        $1:TDNDT,
        $1:TDNTM,
        $1:TDQCE,
        $1:TDQDT,
        $1:TDQTM,
        $1:TDUSR1,
        $1:TDUSR2,
        $1:TDUSR3,
        $1:TDUSR4,
        $1:TDTIME,
        $1:TDMDTE,
        $1:TDMPGM,
        $1:SOURCEDBMS,
        $1:DTL__CAPXRESTART1,
        $1:DTL__CAPXRESTART2,
        $1:DTL__CAPXUOW,
        $1:DTL__CAPXUSER,
        $1:DTL__CAPXTIMESTAMP,
        $1:DTL__CAPXACTION,
        $1:DTL__CAPXCASDELIND,
        $1:DTL__CAPXRRN,
        $1:CDC_INS_DT,
        $1:CDC_UPD_DT,
        $1:CDC_INS_USR,
        $1:CDC_UPD_USR,
        $1:DL_INS_DT,
        $1:DL_INS_USR,
        CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Los_Angeles', 'America/New_York', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP_NTZ) AS INSERT_TIMESTAMP,
        NULL,
        'ADF_USER',
        NULL,
        'WMS'
    FROM @STAGING.sf_dl_wms_parquet_stage/CDC_TDHIST/:DL_FILE_NAME
);

    RETURN 'DONE';
END;
$$;
```

This is how I call my stored procedure:

```
CALL TRANSFORM.SP_WMS_CDC_TDHIST_STAGE_LOAD_COPY(
    'CDC_TDHIST_IncrementalLoad_2023-10-24.snappy.parquet'
);
```

Though stored procedure is getting created, this file `CDC_TDHIST_IncrementalLoad_2023-10-24.snappy.parquet` should get replaced in the dl_file_name of my code when I call the stored procedure.

Comment: You could try constructing a new variable that concatenates the path and the file name and then reference that variable in the FROM statement. You may also need to wrap this in an IDENTIFIER function

Answer (score 0):

to expand on the answer from @NickW in the comment here is what it would look like from my perspective

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
TRANSFORM.SP_WMS_CDC_TDHIST_STAGE_LOAD_COPY(DL_FILE_NAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE 
    res RESULTSET;
    statement string;
BEGIN
statement := 'TRUNCATE TABLE STAGING.TDHIST_STG';
res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :statement);
statement := 'COPY INTO STAGING.TDHIST_STG FROM (
  SELECT
    $1:TDPNT,
    $1:TDCUS,
    $1:TDTIC,
    $1:TDTSK,
    $1:TDOLC,
    $1:TDSEQ,
    $1:TDSL1,
    $1:TDCAS,
    $1:TDQTY,
    $1:TDCUB,
    $1:TDPRD,
    $1:TDBCD,
    $1:TDLIN,
    $1:TDMOP,
    $1:TDMMOP,
    $1:TDTYP,
    $1:TDSDT,
    $1:TDPOI,
    $1:TDSTP,
    $1:TDDCK,
    $1:TDSTS,
    $1:TDRCD,
    $1:TDDCD,
    $1:TDUSR,
    $1:TDCHK,
    $1:TDCSTS,
    $1:TDLDR,
    $1:TDDOR,
    $1:TDLOT,
    $1:TDLTX,
    $1:TDLIC,
    $1:TDPID,
    $1:TDLCE,
    $1:TDLDT,
    $1:TDLTM,
    $1:TDNCE,
    $1:TDNDT,
    $1:TDNTM,
    $1:TDQCE,
    $1:TDQDT,
    $1:TDQTM,
    $1:TDUSR1,
    $1:TDUSR2,
    $1:TDUSR3,
    $1:TDUSR4,
    $1:TDTIME,
    $1:TDMDTE,
    $1:TDMPGM,
    $1:SOURCEDBMS,
    $1:DTL__CAPXRESTART1,
    $1:DTL__CAPXRESTART2,
    $1:DTL__CAPXUOW,
    $1:DTL__CAPXUSER,
    $1:DTL__CAPXTIMESTAMP,
    $1:DTL__CAPXACTION,
    $1:DTL__CAPXCASDELIND,
    $1:DTL__CAPXRRN,
    $1:CDC_INS_DT,
    $1:CDC_UPD_DT,
    $1:CDC_INS_USR,
    $1:CDC_UPD_USR,
    $1:DL_INS_DT,
    $1:DL_INS_USR,
    CONVERT_TIMEZONE(\'America/Los_Angeles\', \'America/New_York\', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP_NTZ) AS INSERT_TIMESTAMP,
    NULL,
    \'ADF_USER\',
    NULL,
    \'WMS\'
FROM @STAGING.sf_dl_wms_parquet_stage/CDC_TDHIST/' || DL_FILE_NAME || '
);'
res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :statement);
RETURN 'DONE';
END;
```

You might also want to check these links out for more information
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-procedure
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables

Hope that helps

Paras

Answer (score 0):

It will be much cleaner if you use the IDENTIFIER function as @NickW pointed out.

The code might look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TRANSFORM.SP_WMS_CDC_TDHIST_STAGE_LOAD_COPY(DL_FILE_NAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE file_path := '@STAGING.sf_dl_wms_parquet_stage/CDC_TDHIST/' || DL_FILE_NAME;
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE STAGING.TDHIST_STG;

    COPY INTO STAGING.TDHIST_STG FROM (
      SELECT
        $1:TDPNT,
        $1:TDCUS,
        $1:TDTIC,
        $1:TDTSK,
        $1:TDOLC,
        $1:TDSEQ,
        $1:TDSL1,
        $1:TDCAS,
        $1:TDQTY,
        $1:TDCUB,
        $1:TDPRD,
        $1:TDBCD,
        $1:TDLIN,
        $1:TDMOP,
        $1:TDMMOP,
        $1:TDTYP,
        $1:TDSDT,
        $1:TDPOI,
        $1:TDSTP,
        $1:TDDCK,
        $1:TDSTS,
        $1:TDRCD,
        $1:TDDCD,
        $1:TDUSR,
        $1:TDCHK,
        $1:TDCSTS,
        $1:TDLDR,
        $1:TDDOR,
        $1:TDLOT,
        $1:TDLTX,
        $1:TDLIC,
        $1:TDPID,
        $1:TDLCE,
        $1:TDLDT,
        $1:TDLTM,
        $1:TDNCE,
        $1:TDNDT,
        $1:TDNTM,
        $1:TDQCE,
        $1:TDQDT,
        $1:TDQTM,
        $1:TDUSR1,
        $1:TDUSR2,
        $1:TDUSR3,
        $1:TDUSR4,
        $1:TDTIME,
        $1:TDMDTE,
        $1:TDMPGM,
        $1:SOURCEDBMS,
        $1:DTL__CAPXRESTART1,
        $1:DTL__CAPXRESTART2,
        $1:DTL__CAPXUOW,
        $1:DTL__CAPXUSER,
        $1:DTL__CAPXTIMESTAMP,
        $1:DTL__CAPXACTION,
        $1:DTL__CAPXCASDELIND,
        $1:DTL__CAPXRRN,
        $1:CDC_INS_DT,
        $1:CDC_UPD_DT,
        $1:CDC_INS_USR,
        $1:CDC_UPD_USR,
        $1:DL_INS_DT,
        $1:DL_INS_USR,
        CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Los_Angeles', 'America/New_York', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP_NTZ) AS INSERT_TIMESTAMP,
        NULL,
        'ADF_USER',
        NULL,
        'WMS'
    FROM IDENTIFIER(:file_path)
);

    RETURN 'DONE';
END;
```

See documentation: [Literals and Variables as Identifiers](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal)